# Best practice for getting average value

Tags: android, audio, fft

I am creating an app that shows the frequency response of an audio signal in the 1/3 octave range.

I have a for loop to get the frequency for each sample. I have if statements to check if samples are within the frequency bands up to 20K

So for example: 
if(freq > 14.1 && freq < 17.8){ //first octave band
     plot this response on graph
}

I usually get one sample for these low frequencies so the is no problem plotting on the graph.

My problem occurs when I get more than one sample in an octave band, I don't know how many samples I am going to get within a band so I can't just do if(freqs in this band == 3) getAvg();

I can't figure out how to know when I have got all the frequencies within a band so I can get the average of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store all the samples inside an array or arraylist.

Once all the samples have been created you can use multiple techniques to calculate the average but the simplest one would be to calculate the sum of all samples and divide it  by the number of samples.

Comment: Hi Edward, I am actually adding the samples to an arraylist, I just don't know when I have got all samples for that frequency band so I can calculate the average

Comment: Why can't you just calculate the average as soon as you leave the for loop? I assume you leave the for loop when you are done sampling right?